# ¿How can I split my text in two columns in a VF rendered as PDF? #CSS Not working properly

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

My code is something like that:

```html
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Account" extensions="CNT_Generar_InfoAbante" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" >

<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        #contenedorBody {
            column-count: 2;
            column-width: 100px;
            column-gap: 20px;
            text-align: justify;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1018px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 1018px;
        }

        .contenedorFooter {
            width: 100%;
            height: 48px;
            max-height 48px;
            /* background: rgb(255, 220, 206); */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div id="contenedorBody">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="contenedorFooter">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="width70">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="width30"><apex:image styleclass="imgFooter" width="145" height="46" value="{!$Resource.imgLogo}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

But still displaying this 
[Image Pdf 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odheR.jpg)
instead like this [Image Pdf 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MxuE.jpg) .

I'm just trying to split my text in two columns, but when I render my page as PDF it looks like the CSS stop working. Could somebody help me? Thank you!